# The event was a great success. In the above sentence, what's the meaning of "event"?

Tags: sentence-usage

The event was a great success.
In the above sentence, what's the meaning of "event"?

Comment: Please look up words in a dictionary such as [this one](https://www.ldoceonline.com/) (do consult multiple dictionaries if the first one doesn't help you) before asking a question about a meaning of a word, and then show us what you've found and how that still doesn't answer your question.

Comment: I found the different meanings. So, I asked this.

Answer (score 2):

In this case "event" refers to a planned activity, probably some kind of meeting where people came together.
This may include people playing music, dancing, giving a presentation or doing exercises (sports).